# R Performance Differential (Solaris vs Windows)

Tags: r, solaris

I noticed an interesting problem.  If I run the following code in R 2.12.0 (32-Bit) on a windows 3.00 gHz Core 2 Duo CPU with 2GB of RAM, it runs in less than one second.  If I run it on a unix-box with sparc-sun-solaris2.10 (Also 32-Bit, though the unix box could run 64-bit) it takes 84 seconds.  The processing speed of the unix box is 2.5 gHz.  If I run top while the code is running, I noticed that my R process is only taking up to ~3.2% of available cpu states, even if more are available.  Could this be part of the problem?  I read the install manual, but nothing jumped out at me as the obvious solution to my problem.  Is the unix operating system somehow limiting available resources while windows is not?  Or, is there some preferable way to compile R from source that was not done?  I apologize if I have not given enough information to answer the problem, this is not really my area of expertise.

```
t0 <- proc.time()[[3]]
x <- rnorm(10000)
for(i in 1:10000){
    sd(x)
}
print(proc.time()[[3]]-t0)
```

Comment: Write a CPU-intensive C program, compile it, run it, see if that gets 3.2% CPU also. If it does, its not R's fault and we can look elsewhere... Also, check CPU time usage from proc.time as well as elapsed time...

Comment: The computationally intensive C program is also capped at ~3.2%.  Also, I just did the same test in MATLAB, where the loop ran in ~1 second on windows, but ~3 seconds on UNIX.  This is turning in to quite the conundrum.

Comment: You sure there's nothing else running on the system?

Comment: No-there are plenty of other sleeping processes on the system, it is a server that is shared by many others.  But even when the CPU states are 90% Idle, my process only gets ~3.2%.  However, the MATLAB test (which was also capped at ~3.2%) leads me to believe it could be an R compilation issue.  If both MATLAB and R run the code in the same time on windows, but R runs 30X longer on UNIX than MATLAB runs (with the same system caps) that seems peculiar.

Comment: I ran it on a Ubuntu Linux 64-bit box and got 1.25 seconds. I got 1.09 seconds on my 64-bit Windows box with the same hardware.

Comment: Does that mean it is a compilation issue for me?  I doubt the 64-bit aspect effects this particular example.

Comment: Solaris allows resource caps (configurable limits for how much of a resource like CPU, memory, I/O specific processes can use) to be set by the system administrator. If such resource controls are in place, your CPU share will max out and your app is throttled. Ask your system administrator whether that's the case. The fact that you report both R and Matlab both "maxing out" at 3.x% seems to indicate that. Also, how many CPUs does the SPARC system have ? If you've got 32, then 3.x% means "one CPU used at 100%", corollary: Process runs singlethreaded.

Comment: How many CPUs do you have? What does `mpstat` say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processors such as the T1 or T2 have a number of cores, and each core has a number of strands (hardware-level context switching). If you can run a multithreaded application, you'll get a large throughput. A typical intended use case would be a Java based web server, processing e.g. 20-40 connections at the same time.

The downside of this type of processors is that single threaded performance of these SPARC chips is quite low. It looks like [Oracle is aware](http://www.oracle.com/us/syndication/podcasts/systems-podcasts-171740.html) of the issue; the current development on T4 focuses on improving the single threaded speed.

The [T1 processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraSPARC_T1) exposes 32 logical CPUs to the operating system. If this was your case, and the displayed value was the percent of total computing power, 1/32 ~= 3.125%, which is close to what you saw.

To squeeze all the performance from a T1 processor, you need to make R use multiple CPUs, for example via the [multicore package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multicore/index.html).